# apache/php + visual studio .net

Tags: .net, apache

I mostly do PHP development but I also do Asp .Net development in VS 2010. VS comes with a built in webserver for debugging. Could VS cause a problem with my apache webserver? Is there a better setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problems as long as those servers do not try to use the same port, but as far as I know, VS internal server usually uses strange ports like 63492, so it is usually not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I like to setup Php/ apache in a vm on my development machine. This keeps the configurations separate from each other. Also saves on overhead if you are running sql on your dev box since you are probably going to have sql server for vs and mysql for Php. If you have the background, use Linux in the vm. It is much happier on the low resources of a vm than windows is.

Comment: I have a server running apache, mysql, php but I'm having a very hard time setting up remote debugging with xdebug. Right now I'm trying local but still not working. I don't get it.

Comment: Is xdebug working on the server? (i.e. show up in a phpinfo(); page)

Comment: yes it is. On local I installed wamp server which comes with xdebug so all the configs should already be there. I also took a look at php.ini and it looks good. Maybe it's the IDE...